# Releasing COM objects in VSTO

Tags: c#, com, vsto

I'm writing an Outlook addin using VSTO. Whenever I need to release a COM object, I'll do this:

```
MailItem email = inbox.Items[1];
// Do something
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(email);
```

However, this becomes a lot of work if I have a lot of COM objects.  I have two code snippets below.  Will either or both of the code snippets below properly release COM objects?

## 1

```
public class Demo
{
    public void Main()
    {
        // Assume inbox exists.
        MailItem email = inbox.Items[1];
        // Do something
        Release(email);
    }

    public void Release(object obj)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
    }
}
```

## 2

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();

MailItem email = inbox.Items[1];
list.add(email);

// Do something

foreach (object obj in list)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
```

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend moving the Release method to a utility class and passing the object byref to ensure the reference remains the same from the calling code.

```
public class ComUtil {
    public static void Release (ref object obj) {
        if(obj != null) {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could call this method from anywhere in your code...

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();

MailItem email = inbox.Items[1];
list.add(email);

// Do something

foreach (object obj in list)
    ComUtil.Release(ref obj);
```